# eliminar texto entre paréntesis de un String en Kotlin

Tags: kotlin

Estoy intentando eliminar caracteres que se encuentran entre parentesis de un string en kotlin

Por ejemplo si tengo:

```
texto uno (eliminar)
```

Desearía obtener esto

```
texto uno
```

**Podría usar algo como esto**

```
var palabra = titulo.split("(").toTypedArray()
var newPalabra = palabra[0]
```

Entonces me quedaría con

```
texto uno
```

**Funciona bien sin embargo, el texto puede tener esta forma**

```
texto (eliminar) uno
```

Entonces me quedaría solo

```
texto
```

Lo que necesito es.

```
texto uno
```

**Nota**
Como se habrán dado cuenta no solo necesito eliminar el contenido en los paréntesis sino también ellos.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Espero que esto te pueda funcionar, yo en mi caso he usado el método replace que lo considero mas útil para una ocasión como esta.

```
fun main() {
        var titulo = "texto (eliminar) uno";
        titulo = titulo.replace("\\((.*?)\\)".toRegex(), "").trim().replace("\\s{2,}".toRegex()," ");
        println(titulo);
       //El primer regex se encarga de eliminar todos los paréntesis () y su contenido.
       //El segundo regex lo uso para los espacios que sean mas grandes se eliminen
       //también, ya que si no, el contenido del mismo queda bastante mal.
}
```

Comment: Justo lo que necesitaba, gracias

Comment: Me alegra, igualmente acabo de actualizarlo, ya que me he dado cuenta de que si al texto le añades otro paréntesis y mas texto, no va muy bien. Ahora con el regex añadido debe ir mucho mejor.